# Source for Hashem standing up for a zaken

Tags: sources-mekorot, kavod, talmud-yerushalmi, anthropomorphism

Yerushalmi, [Bikkurim 3:3](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%99_%D7%91%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%92_%D7%92) (also, [Y. Rosh Hashanah 1:3](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%99_%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%90_%D7%92)) says that Hashem stood up before a zaken for the first time:

> רבי סימון אמר הקב”ה (ויקרא יט) מפני שיבה תקום והדרת פני זקן ויראת
>   מאלהיך אני ה’ אני הוא שקיימתי עמידת זקן תחילה

Where or when did this happen?

Answer (score 2):

SabbaHillel's answer is good, because the Rashi he brought is citing [Bereishit Rabbah](http://daat.ac.il/daat/olam_hatanah/mefaresh.asp?book=1&perek=18&mefaresh=raba), and Bereishit Rabba is the midrash aggadah of the Amoraim of the Yerushalmi.

> וירא אליו ה' באלוני ממרא והוא יושב פתח האהל 
>   כתיב: (תהלים יח) ותתן לי מגן ישעך וימינך תסעדני וענותך תרבני 
>   ותתן לי מגן ישעך, זה אברהם. 
>   וימינך תסעדני, בכבשן האש, ברעבון ובמלכים. 
>   וענותך תרבני, מה ענוה הרבה הקב"ה לאברהם? שהיה יושב והשכינה עומדת, הה"ד: וירא אליו ה':

and also:

> והוא יושב פתח האהל כחום היום 
>   רבי ברכיה משום ר' לוי אמר:
>   ישב כתיב, בקש לעמוד. 
>   אמר לו הקדוש ברוך הוא: שב, אתה סימן לבניך. מה אתה יושב ושכינה עומדת.
>   כך בניך יושבין ושכינה עומדת על גבן. כשישראל נכנסים לבתי כנסיות ולבתי מדרשות וקורין קריאת שמע, והן יושבים לכבודי ואני על גבן, שנאמר: (תהלים פב) אלהים נצב בעדת אל.
>
> אמר רבי חגי בשם ר' יצחק: 
>   עומד אין כתיב: כאן, אלא נצב, אטימוס כמה דתימא, ונצבת על הצור.
>
> כתיב: (ישעיה סה) והיה טרם יקראו ואני אענה 
>   ר' שמואל בר חייא ורבי יודן בשם רבי חנינא:
>   על כל שבח ושבח שישראל משבחין להקב"ה, משרה שכינתו עליהם.

Further reinforcement can be found in the words הה"ד: וירא אליו ה, parallel to the local *veyaresa me'elokecha*.

However, we can refine this further. In Bereishit Rabba, those statements were made by **other** Amoraim, rather than specifically Rabbi Simon.

Later on in Bereishit Rabba (and cited by Rashi on pasuk 22), at the close of the narrative, we have a statement from the same Rabbi Simon, about Hashem standing before Avraham:

> וילכו סדומה ואברהם עודנו עומד לפני ה' 
>   אמר רבי סימון:
>   תיקון סופרים הוא זה, שהשכינה היתה ממתנת לאברהם:

That the verse is politely reverses, and it was Hashem still standing before Avraham. (Even though the word *mamtenes* appears.) So this was surely in Rabbi Simon cognizance.

Answer (score 1):

We see this from [Vayera 18:1](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8213/jewish/Chapter-18.htm#showrashi=true). As Rashi said, Hashem stood before Avraham as a sign that he would "stand" before the judges of Bnai Yisrael.

> Now the Lord appeared to him in the plains of Mamre, and he was
>   sitting at the entrance of the tent when the day was hot.

**Rashi**

> **was sitting:** It is written יֹשֵׁב [without a “vav,” and may therefore be read: “he sat”]. He wished to stand. The Holy One,
>   blessed be He, said to him, “Sit and I will stand, and you will be a
>   sign for your children that I am destined to stand in the congregation
>   of the judges, and they will sit,” as it is said (Ps. 82: 1): “God
>   stands in the Divine assembly.” - [from Gen. Rabbah 48:7]

Comment: How do you see that this is the event the Yerushalmi is referring to? Sure, Hashem is standing before Avraham. But do you know that it's this event specifically that the Gemara is discussing?

Comment: @DonielF This is the earliest time such a thing happened and the question is asking for the first time.